# How to use a default value with parameter sets in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have this function

```
Function Do-ThisOrThat
{
[cmdletbinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName="First")]
    [string]$FirstParam = "MyFirstParam",

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName="Second")]
    [string]$SecondParam
    )
    Write-Output "Firstparam: $FirstParam. SecondParam $SecondParam"
}
```

If I call the function like this `Do-ThisOrThat` I want it to detect that the $FirstParam has a default value and use that. Is it possible? Running it as is only works if I specify a parameter.

e.g. this works: `Do-ThisOrThat -FirstParam "Hello"`

Comment: `if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'First' -and -not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('FirstParam')){ <# $FirstParam has default value #> }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell PowerShell which of your parameter sets is the default one:

```
[cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName="First")]
```

This will allow you to invoke `Do-ThisOrThat` without any parameters as well as with a `-SecondParameter` value, and `$FirstParam` will have its default value in both cases.

Note, however, that based on how your parameter sets are defined, if you do specify an argument, you can't do so *positionally* - you must use the parameter name (`-FirstParam` or `-SecondParam`).

Answer (score 3):

This question is a bit ambiguous.

If you want to set the default parameter set, use the `DefaultParameterSetName` property in the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='First')]
```

If, on the other hand you want to detect and infer whether `$FirstParam` has its default value inside the script, you can check which parameter set has been determined and whether `FirstParam` parameter was specified by the caller, like this:

```
if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'First' -and -not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('FirstParam')){ 
  <# $FirstParam has default value #> 
}
```