# Is there a way to make a Powershell function ignore a default parameter's value if its parameter set is not in use?

Tags: powershell

I understand [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931204/how-to-use-a-default-value-with-parameter-sets-in-powershell/42931341#42931341) that when you have default parameters and multiple parameter sets in a Powershell function, the default parameter values will be instantiated even if the parameter set in use is not the one in which they are inserted.
Is there a way to avoid this?

For example, in the function below, assuming that there is a really expensive calculation used to compute the default value of `$FirstParameter`, I would like to avoid using it when it is not necessary:

```
function PrintStuff {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='FirstSet')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='FirstSet')]
        [String]$FirstParameter=(ReallyExpensiveFunction),

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='SecondSet')]
        [String]$SecondParameter
    )

    if (-not ($FirstParameter -eq $null)) {Write-Host $FirstParameter}
    Write-Host "$($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)"
}

function ReallyExpensiveFunction {
    # Very expensive calculation
    "I Am First"
}
```

However, at the moment running it would still give me the results below:

```
PS C:\> PrintStuff
# I Am First
# FirstSet

PS C:\> PrintStuff -SecondParameter "don't print this"
# I Am First
# SecondSet
```

As per above, when `SecondSet` is used `$FirstParameter` is still being defined. Is there a way to get only `SecondSet` printed when the second parameter set is used?

Bear in mind, I am looking to find out if there is a solution which would allow me to keep `ReallyExpensiveFunction` as the default value for `$FirstParameter`, and avoid solutions which would involve transferring the logic to the body of the function, such as:

```
...
    Param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='FirstSet')]
        [String]$FirstParameter,
    ...
    )

    if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'FirstSet' -and ($FirstParameter -eq '')) {
        $FirstParameter = ReallyExpensiveFunction
    }
...
```

Sorry if the pitch is too specific, but I am curious to find out if this is possible.

Comment: Interesting question, +1 as got me curious too. Gave it a go and so far no/beyond the scope of my knowledge. My approach would be handle in function body as in your question, or pass `$($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)` to `ReallyExpensiveFunction` (which can exit prior to expensive operations if this is `SecondSet`)

Comment: Considering that you are telling the first parameter value to be set to the function whether it is passed to the function or not (that's what you are telling it to do), it kinda defies logic to want it not be set, don't you think?

Comment: Good point, @gms0ulman, about passing `$($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)` as an argument. `ReallyExpensiveFunction` can also be wrapped in another one if (as is my case) it cannot be modified because other functions rely on it.
Still it would be nice to find an answer with whether the 'skip this parameter if is not current parameterset' functionality exists within Powershell, or exactly why it doesn't. I'll keep researching and see if I can find it, or wait until others do, and if not I think I should accept the above as an elegant workaround for it.

Comment: @AdilHindistan, I think within a single parameter set, it would be counter-intuitive. But to me, since Powershell offers the facility to create various parameter sets, it would also make sense that a function would only try to run default arguments which are contained within a set. E.g., a function `RunTests` which has one parameter set allowing the user to specify a test manually, and a default one which would load all existing tests within a suite. The latter may be the default, but the user would have the option to specify a single test instead. This is how I see the logic in this scope.

Comment: You can use a `[ValidateScript()]` to assign it only when another parameter is `$Null` or something of that nature.

Comment: ParameterSet is filtering what you can see when passing the arguments, it is not selectively setting the variables. PowerShell is still going through each parameter to set its 'defaults', if you have specified one. If you put the script in debugger mode you will see that. So, that's how PS behaves, in my opinion doing the right thing. what you are really after is possible in many ways, just not the way you think it should be :)

Comment: Thanks @AdilHindistan. That's kind of what I was looking for, so it answers it for me. If you submit it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. ParameterSet allows to present a simpler interface to user for complex argument sets by filtering out the non-relevant ones. However, PowerShell  goes through each parameter, whether it is in the selected parameterset or not and assign the default value to the parameter, if you specify one. So, simply put in the context of your question, ParameterSet may be thought as just a filter for presentation.